# Speed problem of model.fit() in TF2 when loading data using DataGenerator

Tags: keras, classification

I run a simple classification problem with a small dataset on tf2 with two different ways on how to load the data.

In the first way, I loaded the data by reading images and loading them into (train_x, train_y) and (test_w,test_y).
The training was quite fast and fine.

Then, I wanted to try with using DataGenerator as such

```
training_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale = 1./255,
      rotation_range=15,

      fill_mode='nearest')


validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

train_generator = training_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAINING_DIR,
    target_size=(224,224),
    class_mode='categorical'
)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    VALIDATION_DIR,
    target_size=(224,224),
    class_mode='categorical'
)
```

and then I run the training with the command

```
H = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    batch_size=2,
    validation_data= validation_generator,
    verbose = 1,
    epochs=EPOCHS)
```

then, the training becomes extremely slow. One epoch lasts several minutes, while in the previous case, the whole training was less than 15 seconds.

I did not understand what is the problem. It seems this problem is shared among several developers but not clear why the training becomes so slow when using a data generator.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was also addressed here 
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12683#issuecomment-614963118